# Django set form value equal to another form value in template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to get the following goal: I have two forms in one view, form1 and form2. The model are the following:

```
Class Model1(models.Model):
 var_1=models.CharField()
 var_2=models.CharField

Class Model2(models.Model):
 var_1=models.CharField()
 var_3=models.CharField
```

I have just set both form in the same view with a single submit button. Now I want to have the possibility to set `var_1` from the `form1` also for the `var_1` of the `Model2` (becouse are equal) when the client fill the `form1`. It's possible to get it?
This one my views.py

```
def example(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form1 = Model1Form(request.POST)
         form2 = Model2Form(request.POST)
         if form1.is_valid() and form2.isvalid():
             print("Il form è valido")
             new_input1 = form1.save()
             new_input2=form2.save()

    else :
        form1 = Model1Form()
        form2 = Model2Form()


    context= {
        'form1': form1,
        'form2':form2,
            }

    return render(request, "", context)
```

Comment: Can you share your view?

Comment: I have added it just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest that you set the value of the field from the other form before saving.

```
if form1.is_valid() and form2.isvalid():
    form2.cleaned_data['var_1'] = form1.cleaned_data['var_1']
    form1.save()
    form2.save()
```

I assume that you are not showing the `var_1` field on both forms? If you were showing both this would overwrite the value of `var_1` for `form2`.